# Angularfire2 Firestore Update same field in multiple documents

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have a profile table and a jobs table stored on Firebase Firestore.  I am creating an Angular 5 web site.  To save on network calls i added the users profile name to each job document.  (Not sure if firestore has table linking).  So when the user updates him name, I also have to update their job documents (not many).  I can get a collection of jobs with the right user id.  But i cannot figure out how to iterate through the list and update the one field without using an Observable (one time call).  Here is what I tried that forced my browser into a continous loop

```
jobsCollection : AngularFirestoreCollection<Job>;
jobDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Job>;

jobs: Observable<Job[]>;
job: Observable<Job>;

update(profile: Profile){
  this.jobsCollection = this.db.collection('jobs', ref => {
    return ref.where('user_id', '==',profile.user_id);
  });

  this.tracksCollection.valueChanges(item => {

    console.log('update this record:', item);

    item.forEach(job=> {
      console.log('This is the job');
      this.jobDoc = this.db.doc(`jobs/${job.id}`);
      job.name= profile.name;
      this.jobDoc.update(job);
    });


  });

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks
PK

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a `.subscribe()` to get the data from `this.jobsCollection` and iterate through each and update the doc like

```
this.jobsCollection.snapshotChanges().map(changes=>{
      return changes.map(a=>{
          const data = a.payload.doc.data();
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return {id, ...data}
      })
    }).subscribe(items=>{
        items.forEach(job=>{
            this.db.doc(`jobs/${job.id}`).update({name:profile.name});
        })
     });
```

I assume you have a filed called `id` inside each doc under`jobs` collection, otherwise you need to use `.snapshotChanges()` instead of `.valueChanges()`

Comment: ya unfortunately the job returned does not include the id.  So when i use job.id I the error 'No document to update'  @ /documents/jobs/undefined

Comment: Oh thank you, thank you, thank you.  As a side note, do you have an opinion if doing this update on the client, when they change their name is better than doing it in a firebase cloud function, triggered by an update to their profile.  I have it working fine (If not a slight delay) in a cloud function.

Comment: i think doing it in the cloud function is the right approach. then you are sure the fields are updated.