# AngularFirestore: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot<any>'

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is an Angular5 and Firestore issue

**What I want to do**

- Grab a Firestore Collection, which in my database is called `minutes`
- Set my component variable, also called `minutes`, equal to an Observable object that includes each `minute` document ID.

Right now I'm getting this error

`Property 'id' does not exist on type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot<any>'`

This is where I gather my collection from Firestore

```
minutesArray: AngularFirestoreCollection<any>;
minutes: Observable<any[]>;

constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
  this.minutesArray = afs.collection<any>('minutes', ref => ref.orderBy('year', 'desc'));
  this.minutes = this.minutesArray
                   .snapshotChanges()
                   .pipe(map(actions => actions.map(a => {
                       const data = a.payload.doc.data();
                       #### NEXT LINE ERRORS OUT ####
                       const id = a.payload.doc.id;
                       return { id, ...data };
                     }))
                   );
```

Why is this error being thrown?

This [Github Issue](http://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1695) did not provide answers.

`

Comment: So the solution in the bottom of Github issue you’ve attached didn’t work? Note they have 2 returns and yours only has one..

Comment: Their solution throws the same error.

Comment: This [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49084835/angularfire2-firestore-update-same-field-in-multiple-documents) post has a good answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angularfire2 Firestore Update same field in multiple documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49084835/angularfire2-firestore-update-same-field-in-multiple-documents)

Answer (score 4):

Try to use:

```
doc.payload.doc['id']
```

Instead of:

```
doc.payload.doc.id
```

Comment: in your case is a.payload.doc['id']

Answer (score 1):

Enabling `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` in the tsconfig.json resolved this issue for me

```
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
```

Comment: This worked, but why?